# Target classes inner HTML based on URL parameters

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, url-parameters

I asked a similar question about customizing the inner HTML of span id's, and although it worked perfectly, I'm looking for a solution that will let me use multiple instances of the same target on the same page (doesn't work with id's since they need to be unique).

Right now, I am targeting elements with something like
`<span id="organization">placeholder</span>`
but I want to be able to use the same "organization" placeholder in multiple spots.

This is the current script:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;

var parameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

for (const parameter of parameters) {
    document.getElementById(parameter[0]).innerHTML = parameter[1];
}
```

I've tried targeting the classes instead by both name (getElementsByName) and class (getElementsByClassName) but am having trouble keeping the above script working with dynamic URL parameters.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind by `getElementsByClassName`, but you need to convert from `HTMLCollection` to an `array` by spread operator, also you can use `forEach` to loop throw each element and set the `innerHTML`.

Here if you set for example

?one=1&two=2

There element whose `class="one"` should be fill with `1` and same for `two`

html:

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

js:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;

var parameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

for (const parameter of parameters) {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName(parameter[0])].forEach(element => element.innerHTML = parameter[1]);
}
```